# How to use addition in long long int?

Tags: c++, variables, int

i have write a code for addition with the variable long long but the summary is not like the normal addition

here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long int a, b, c;
cout << "" << "";
cin >> a >> b;
c = abs(a) + abs(b);
cout << c;
cout << "\n";
}
```

when i input number like 1000000000000000000 2

the outpout is 1486618626 not 1000000000000000002

Comment: Because you added `using namespace std;` I dont know if its picking up the C++ or the C function, but in C the abs function takes and returns int, for long long its llabs. Yet another reason why `using namespace std;` is bad.

Comment: This works perfectly OK for me ([demo](http://ideone.com/19dOYm)). Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'd consider this a valid question. Whether the code above works as intendet is compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old C function `::abs` from `<stdlib.h>` takes and returns `int`, which cannot hold values that big on your platform.

Use `std::abs` from `<cmath>` (C++17 and later) or `<cstdlib>` instead.

Also, get rid of that `using namespace std;` and properly qualify the names instead. See [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3002139)

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    long long int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    long long int c = std::abs(a) + std::abs(b);
    std::cout << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It works for me with `::abs` from <stdlib.h> `1000000000000000000
5
1000000000000000005`

Comment: @FilipKočica That's allowed to happen, but it's not portable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<cmath>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`.

Also, don't add values while abs()ing them. Do it this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int a, b;
    long long int c;

    cin >> a >> b;

    a = abs(a);
    b = abs(b);

    c = a + b;
    cout << c;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Code works just fine.

Input and output:

```
1000000000000000000 2
1000000000000000002
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding the values while "absing" them.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't know if you're targeting me or something but I don't like you. Saying this in a respective manner.

Here is my result when I add them while they're "absing".

1000000000000000000 2
1000000000000000000

When I do it my way it works. Can you explain that too? Instead of saying nothing wrong?

Comment: well the <cstdlib> , work well for me without change the code

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman Don't worry, I'm not targeting anyone, I just watch the tag C++. Regarding your question, feel free to post that as an actual question with a MCVE and I'm sure someone will handle it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen okay then, I'm posting a new question. I hope you can get me an answer for it, because I don't know.